# what is "ein-" in the construct "Ein- nach d- ander-"

Tags: grammatical-case, article, declension, indefinite-pronoun

Could someone explain in the following examples, how the declension of "ein-" works?

1. "die eines nach dem anderen einschlafenden Kinder"
2. "die einer nach dem anderen durchstartenden Halbstarken"
3. "die eine nach der anderen loskichernden Frauen"

If "ein-" is an indefinite article,  "eines" would be the masculin genitive, "einer" would be the feminine genitive and "eine" could be the feminine nominative/accusative, which doesn't seem to be right.

What is "ein-" in that case?

Comment: None of your example is idiomatic. I feel like they're even wrong.

Comment: Source from Google Books: https://books.google.de/books?id=P1dbDAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA278&ots=HaPq2zgu1k&dq=%22ein%20nach%20d%20ander%22%20struktur&pg=PA278#v=onepage&q=%22ein%20nach%20d%20ander%22%20struktur&f=false

Comment: @Em1 how so? While the particular examples might be a bit odd, I don't see anything unidiomatic here, even though relative clause constructions (*die Kinder, die eins nach dem anderen einschlafen/einschliefen,*) are more common in spoken language.

Comment: @Chieron *Way more common*! As part of the adjective it's quite weird, that's why it even felt wrong to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your examples, *eine/einer/eines* is an indefinite pronoun in nominative singular. It refers to the subject (*die Kinder*, *die Halbstarken*, *die Frauen*), so it is nominative and it refers to one person of the group, so it is singular.

> die einschlafenden Kinder -> eines der Kinder
>   die durchstartenden Halbstarken -> einer der Halbstarken
>   die loskichernden Frauen -> eine der Frauen